# Letter-replacement challenge

Tags: code-golf, string

The idea is simple. You've to create a "visualised" letter-replacement, by providing 3 strings (input can be comma separated, separate inputs, or as an array). The first segment is the word you want to correct, and the second segment is the letters you want to replace, and the third segment is the replacement for the letters in segment 2.

For example:

```
|    | Input                       | Starting Word | Output      |
|----|-----------------------------|---------------|-------------|
| #1 | Hello world -wo -ld +Ea +th | Hello world   | Hello Earth |
| #2 | Hello World -wo -ld +Ea +th | Hello World   | Hello Worth |
| #3 | Hello -llo +y               | Hello         | Hey         |
| #4 | Red -R -d +Gr +en           | Red           | Green       |
| #5 | mississippi -is -i +lz +p   | mississippi   | mlzslzspppp |
| #6 | Football -o -a +a +i        | Football      | Fiitbill    |
| #7 | mississippi -is -i +iz +p   | mississippi   | mpzspzspppp |
```

#### Explanation

The replacements are to be done step-by-step with their respective pair. Here's an illustration with an input of `mississippi -is -i +iz +p` to give the output `mpzspzsppp` (see example `#7` above)

```
| Step  | Input                         | Output        |
|------ |---------------------------    |-------------  |
| #1    | mississippi -is -i +iz +p     |               |
| #2    | mississippi -is +iz           | mizsizsippi   |
| #3    | mizsizsippi -i +p             | mpzspzspppp   |
```

#### Rules

- Inputs are always in this order `<starting_string> <list_of_letters_to_replace> <replacement_letters>`.
- Letters to replace and replacement groups will never be mixed (ie: there will never be `-a +i -e +o`).
- Letters to replace are *always* prefixed with `-` and replacement letters are always prefixed with `+`. (The prefix is mandatory)
- There may be more than one set of letters to replace, so you'd need to look at the prefix.
- Assume the amount of letter groups to replace and the amount of replacement letter groups are always equal (ie: there will never be `-a -e +i`)
- Replacements are case-sensitive (see example `#1` and `#2`).
- Replacements are done in the order they were given in the input.
- Letter replacements can be replaced with other replacements. See example `#6`.
- The first segment (starting word) will *never* include `-` or `+` characters.
- This is code-golf so shortest bytes win.

### Leaderboards

<sup>Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.</sup>

<sup>To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:</sup>

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

<sup>where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:</sup>

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

<sup>If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:</sup>

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

<sup>You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:</sup>

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=96473,OVERRIDE_USER=38505;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Given rules 2 and 5, you really don't need to look at the prefix. With n inputs, input 0 is the base string, inputs 1 to int(n/2) are `letter to replace` (with prefix `-`) and input int(n/2)+1 to n-1 are `replacement` (with prefix `+`)

Comment: @edc65 100% true, although the challenge was designed to have the prefix (and I could make up some weird explanation that I'm an alien who cannot process letter replacements without their prefix) but in reality, it's just another barrier to stop this being too trivial - though looking at the current answers (all are great by the way) it wasn't a complex barrier. Also fun fact, the idea behind this challenge was spawned from my friend in a Skype chat. He'd mis-spell a word (`gello`), and then send me the letter replacements (`-g +h`) because he wanted to be annoying instead of sending `hello*`.

Comment: _Inputs are always in this order_ Why so restrictive?

Comment: @LuisMendo I guess it doesn't really matter - but it's the way my friend and I formatted it, but since answers have been posted to this requirement, I cannot really make a rule change. It wasn't questioned on the sandbox, so I didn't think of it as a negative.

Comment: Is the base string guaranteed to contain only letters and spaces without punctuation marks?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, in fact the starting word will *only* be 1 or 2 words (special characters, hyphens).

Comment: By "base string", I meant the whole expression on which replacements are applied, not just the first word. `"Hello world"` is definitely two space-separated words. :-)

Comment: @Arnauld ah sorry, very light sleep last night. Yes, you're right. The base string character set is `[a-zA-Z\+\-\s]`

Comment: Example `#2` is wrong (duplicate of `#1`). I don't know what it was supposed to be, but it should probably support the "Replacements are case-sensitive" rule (which neither `#1` nor `#2` really do).

Comment: @udioica is perfecly right and it in fact support  the "Replacements are case-sensitive" rule. Run the snippet in the JavaScript answer to see it implemented. (#1 **w**orld` vs #2 **W**orld)

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```
f=(s,n=1,l=s.split(/ \W/))=>(r=l[n+l.length/2|0])?f(s.split(l[n]).join(r),n+1):l[0]
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(s,n=1,l=s.split(/ \W/))=>(r=l[n+l.length/2|0])?f(s.split(l[n]).join(r),n+1):l[0]

console.log(f("Hello world -wo -ld +Ea +th"));
console.log(f("Hello World -wo -ld +Ea +th"));
console.log(f("Hello -llo +y"));
console.log(f("Red -R -d +Gr +en"));
console.log(f("mississippi -is -i +lz +p"));
console.log(f("Football -o -a +a +i"));
console.log(f("mississippi -is -i +iz +p"));
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 17 bytes

```
IIð¡€áIð¡€á‚øvy`:
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=SUnDsMKh4oKsw6FJw7DCoeKCrMOh4oCaw7h2eWA6&input=bWlzc2lzc2lwcGkKLWlzIC1pCitpeiArcA)

**Explanation**

```
I                   # read starting string
 I                  # read letters to be replaced
  ð¡                # split on space
    €á              # and remove "-"
      I             # read replacement letters
       ð¡           # split on space
         €á         # and remove "+"
           ‚ø       # zip to produce pairs of [letters to replace, replacement letters]
             vy`:   # for each pair, replace in starting string
```

Or with a less strict input format

```
vy`:
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dnlgOg&input=W1snaXMnLCAnaXonXSxbJ2knLCAncCddXQptaXNzaXNzaXBwaQ)

Answer (score 5):

### Pyke, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
z[zdcmt)[.:
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=z%5Bzdcmt%29%5B.%3A&input=Hello+world%0A-wo+-ld%0A%2BEa+%2Bth%0A)

```
z           - input()
 [zdcmt)    - def func():
  zdc       -  input().split(" ")
     mt     -  map(>[1:], ^)
            - func()
        [   - func()
         .: - translate()
```

Or 2 bytes if in a different input format:

```
.:
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.%3A&input=%5B%22wo%22%2C+%22ld%22%5D%0A%5B%22Ea%22%2C+%22th%22%5D%0AHello+world&warnings=0)

Comment: At work catbus.co.uk is blocked. Are you able to link an alternative test suite please?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I don't believe conforming to your (arbitrary) work firewall settings is reasonable.

Comment: @orlp - I agree, it's shit. But I don't set the firewall settings. I just wanted to test it out

Comment: @hd you can download Pyke at github.com/muddyfish/pyke

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 58 bytes

**57 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

Requires first item on one line, then the replacements on the next. Big thanks to [@Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada) who came up with a different approach to help reduce by 4 bytes!

```pl
$a=<>;1while$a=~s%-(\S*)(.*?)\+(\S*)%"s/$1/$3/g;q{$2}"%ee
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -pe '$a=<>;1while$a=~s%-(\S*)(.*?)\+(\S*)%"s/$1/$3/g;q{$2}"%ee' <<< 'Football
-o -a +a +i'
Fiitbill
```

```sh
perl -pe '$a=<>;1while$a=~s%-(\S*)(.*?)\+(\S*)%"s/$1/$3/g;q{$2}"%ee' <<< 'mississippi
-is -i +iz +p'
mpzspzspppp
```

```sh
perl -pe '$a=<>;1while$a=~s%-(\S*)(.*?)\+(\S*)%"s/$1/$3/g;q{$2}"%ee' <<< 'mississippi
-ippi -i -mess +ee +e +tenn'
tennessee
```

Comment: 4 bytes longer, there is `perl -pE 's/(.*?) -(\S*)(.*?)\+(\S*)/"(\$1=~s%$2%$4%gr).\"$3\""/ee&&redo'`. I can't manage to get it any shorter, but maybe you can :)

Comment: Gotcha! 58 bytes : `perl -pE '$a=<>;1while$a=~s%-(\S*)(.*?)\+(\S*)%"s/$1/$3/g;q{$2}"%ee'`. (takes the string on one line, and the "flags" on the next line)

Comment: Awesome! I'm not at a computer but I'll update that tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about removing the q{} surrounding $2 ? Wouldn't this fail when there are 3 - and 3 + switches? (I can't test it now, so maybe you were right so remove it ;) )

Comment: @Dada ahhh, I did wonder why you'd added it, I tested all the cases in the test suite, but didn't think about a 3 for 3 replacement...

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```
for($s=$argv[$i=1];$v=$argv[++$i];)$r[$v[0]>'+'][]=substr($v,1);echo str_replace($r[1],$r[0],$s);
```

This challenge describes the exact behaviour of str_replace so for php it's all about making the arrays of replacements. I tried to do it using only one "substring" but that might not be the best solution. Use like:

```
php -r "for($s=$argv[$i=1];$v=$argv[++$i];)$r[$v[0]>'+'][]=substr($v,1);echo str_replace($r[1],$r[0],$s);" "mississippi" "-is" "-i" "+iz" "+p"
```

edit: 1 byte saved thanks to Titus

Comment: This is probably the shortest thing possible. But `$v[0]>'+'` saves one byte over `$v[0]=='-'`. You could also use `ord($v)&4` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## GNU sed 86 Bytes

Includes +1 for -r

```
:;s,^([^-]*)(\w+)([^-]*-)\2( [^+]*\+)(\w*),\1\5\3\2\4\5,
t;s,-[^-+]*,,;s,\+[^-+]*,,;t
```

[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=OjtzLChbXi1dfF4pKFx3KykoW14tXSotKVwyKCBbXitdKlwrKShcdyopLFwxXDVcM1wyXDRcNSwKdDtzLC1bXi0rXSosLDtzLFwrW14tK10qLCw7dA&input=SGVsbG8gd29ybGQgLXdvIC1sZCArRWEgK3RoCkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIC13byAtbGQgK0VhICt0aApIZWxsbyAtbGxvICt5ClJlZCAtUiAtZCArR3IgK2VuCm1pc3Npc3NpcHBpIC1pcyAtaSArbHogK3AKRm9vdGJhbGwgLW8gLWEgK2EgK2kKbWlzc2lzc2lwcGkgLWlzIC1pICtpeiArcA&args=LXI)

Example:

```
$ echo 'Hello world -wo -ld +Ea +th'|sed -rf replace.sed
Hello Earth
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>153</s> 133 bytes

```
String c(String[]a){String r=a[0],z[]=a[1].split(" ?-");for(int i=0;i<z.length;r=r.replace(z[i],a[2].split(" ?[+]")[i++]));return r;}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/FmSlYw)

```
class M{
  static String c(String[] a){
    String r = a[0],
           z[] = a[1].split(" ?-");
    for(int i = 0; i < z.length; r = r.replace(z[i], a[2].split(" ?[+]")[i++]));
    return r;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "Hello world", "-wo -ld", "+Ea +th" }));
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "Hello World", "-wo -ld", "+Ea +th" }));
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "Hello", "-llo", "+y" }));
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "Red", "-R -d", "+Gr +en" }));
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "mississippi", "-is -i", "+lz +p" }));
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "Football", "-o -a", "+a +i" }));
    System.out.println(c(new String[]{ "mississippi", "-is -i", "+iz +p" }));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello Earth
Hello Worth
Hey
Green
mlzslzspppp
Fiitbill
mpzspzspppp
```

Comment: Does this work for the input `new String[]{'Rom Ro. Rom", "-Ro." , "+No."}`? Just writing something that (hopefully) matches a wrong regex.

Comment: @RomanGräf Yes, works and outputs `Rom No. Rom`. Btw, you can try it yourself by clicking the `Try it here.` link in the post, and then fork it. :)

Comment: I know but I'm currently on my mobile. :(

Answer (score 2):

## R, <strike>98</strike> 94 bytes

Edit: saved 4 bytes thanks to @rturnbull

```
i=scan(,"");s=i[1];i=gsub("\\+|-","",i[-1]);l=length(i)/2;for(j in 1:l)s=gsub(i[j],i[l+j],s);s
```

**Ungolfed and test cases**

Because `scan` (reads input from stdin) doesn't work properly in R-fiddle I showcase the program by wrapping it in a function instead. Note that the function takes a vector as an input and can be run by e.g.: `f(c("Hello world", "-wo", "-ld", "+Ea", "+th"))`. The gofled program above would prompt the user to input using stdin whereby typing `"Hello world" -wo -ld -Ea +th` in the console would yield the same result.

[Run the code on R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ZleCbk79)

```
f=function(i){
    s=i[1]                                   # Separate first element
    i=gsub("\\+|-","",i[-1])                 # Remove + and - from all elements except first, store as vector i
    l=length(i)/2                            # calculate the length of the vector i (should always be even)
    for(j in 1:l)s=gsub(i[j],i[l+j],s)       # iteratively match element j in i and substitute with element l+j in i
    s                                        # print to stdout
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a test suite link also, please?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ added an R-fiddle test suite. Note that the test suite uses a function instead of reading input from stdin as explained in the edited answer.

Comment: Is this answer valid, since you have to use `"` around the input string?

Comment: @rturnbull I don't see why not. Wrapping every entry with quotes and pressing enter would yield the equivalent result (e.g.: `"Hello world" => enter => "-wo" => enter => "-ld" => enter =>  "+Ea" => enter =>"+th"`) which is usually how strings are read anyways.

Comment: Right, but the input in the challenge specification in the OP does not include quotes.

Comment: @rturnbull I understand your point but simply including quotes does not invalidate the input (see other answers). However, one could argue that input has to be on the form: `c("Hello world", "-wo -ld", "+Ea +th")` such that one has to split the two last elements on white space. It seems unnecessary to me thoguh but I will of course update the answer if that's required. OP did not complain about the test suite given which uses same input vector, albeit, did not reply again either.

Comment: Yeah it's really up to the OP! I personally like your answer as-is, but I was worried that it might be invalid. Looking at answers for other languages it seems like quotes are pretty accepted. While I have your attention, I think you can golf off 4 bytes by changing `l=length(i)` to `l=length(i)/2` and updating the later references to `l`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 164 Bytes

```
preg_match_all("#^[^-+]+|-[\S]+|[+][\S]+#",$argv[1],$t);for($s=($a=$t[0])[0];++$i<$c=count($a)/2;)$s=str_replace(trim($a[+$i],"-"),trim($a[$i+$c^0],"+"),$s);echo$s;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 25 bytes

`qq+dE+r-PdiW:1s<C-R>"-g<CR>@qq@q`

Assumes input in this format:

```
mississippi
-is -i
+lz +p
```

- `+dE+r-PdiW`: Combines `-` and `+` into single register, with the `+` turned into a `-`.
- `:1s<C-R>"-g`: Uses the register as a code snippet, inserted directly into the `:s` command, with `-` as the separator.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>85</s> 78 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
g=map tail.words
a#b=foldl(flip$uncurry replace)a.zip(g b).g
```

Usage example: `("mississippi" # "-is -i") "+lz +p"` -> `"mlzslzspppp"`.

How it works:

```
g=map tail.words              -- helper function that splits a string into a
                              -- list of words (at spaces) and drops the first
                              -- char of each word

                zip(g b).g    -- make pairs of strings to be replaced and its
                              -- replacement
foldl(flip$uncurry replace)a  -- execute each replacement, starting with the
                              -- original string
                              -- -> "flip" flips the arguments of "uncurry replace"
                              --           i.e. string before pair of replacements
                              -- "uncurry" turns a function that expects two
                              --           lists into one that expects a list of pairs
```

Edit: @BlackCap found 6 bytes to save and I myself another one.

Comment: 6 bytes: `import Data.Lists;a#b=foldl(uncurry replace`flip`)a.zip(g b).g;g=map tail.words`

Comment: @BlackCap: Nice, thanks!  No need to make `flip` infix. Standard prefix is one byte shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Convex](http://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 19 bytes

```
¶:äz{S*"-+"-ä~@\ò}/
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=wrY6w6R6e1MqIi0rIi3DpH5AXMOyfS8&input=&args=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ+LVdvIC1sZA+K0VhICt0aA&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 93 byte

```
def f(s):
  s,m,p=s
  for n,o in zip(m.split(),p.split()):s=s.replace(n[1:],o[1:])
  return s
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Dxv1/1)

Input is a list with strings, replacement strings are space separated.

Example input:
`['mississippi','-is -i','+iz +p']`

Comment: Are you able to add a test suite link, please?

Comment: Link provided and also reduced size a little.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 90 bytes

```
param($a,$b,$c)-split$b|%{$a=$a-creplace($_-replace'-'),((-split$c)[$i++]-replace'\+')};$a
```

Takes input as three arguments, with the `-` and `+` strings space-separated. Performs a `-split` on `$b` (the `-split` when acting in a unary fashion splits on whitespace), then loops `|%{...}` through each of those. Every iteration we're removing the `-`, finding the next `[$i++]` replacement string and removing the `+` from it, and using the `-creplace` (case-sensitive replacement) to slice and dice `$a` and store it back into `$a`. Then, `$a` is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\letter-replacement-challenge.ps1 'mississippi' '-is -i' '+iz +p'
mpzspzspppp

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\letter-replacement-challenge.ps1 'Hello world' '-wo -ld' '+Ea +th'
Hello Earth

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\letter-replacement-challenge.ps1 'Hello World' '-wo -ld' '+Ea +th'
Hello Worth
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 106 bytes

```
for($s=($v=$argv)[$i=1];$i++<$n=$argc/2;)$s=str_replace(substr($v[$i],1),substr($v[$n+$i-1],1),$s);echo$s;
```

straight forward approach. Run with `php -r '<code> <arguments>`.