# C.U.S.R.S - The Completely Useless String Refactoring System!

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

I'm a real big fan of the SBU (Short But Unique) challenges that crop up on PPCG all of the time. The CUSRS is a system designed to refactor strings, a CUSRS function takes 2 parameters and outputs 1 String.

## Challenge

Produce a program, function, lambda or acceptable alternative to do the following:

Given `String input` and `String refactor` (as examples), refactor `input` using `refactor` as follows:

The `refactor` String will be in the format of `((\+|\-)\w* *)+` (regex), for example:

```
+Code -Golf -lf +al
```

Each section is a refactoring action to perform on `input`. Each program also has a pointer.

`+` Will insert it's suffix (without the plus) at the pointers current location in the String and then reset the pointer to 0.

Each operation should be applied to the `input` String and the result should be returned.

Example:

```
input:
Golf +Code //pointer location: 0

output:
CodeGolf //pointer location: 0
```

`-` Will increment the pointer through the String until it finds the suffix. The suffix will be removed from the String and the pointer will be left on the left side of the removed text.  If no suffix is found the pointer will simply progress to the end of the String and be left there.

```
input:
Golf -lf //pointer location 0

output:
Go //pointer location 2
```

## Examples

```
input:
"Simple" "-impl +nip -e +er"

output:
"Sniper"

input:
"Function" "-F +Conj"

output:
"Conjunction"

input:
"Goal" "+Code -al +lf"

output:
"CodeGolf"

input:
"Chocolate" "Chocolate"

output:
"Chocolate" //Nothing happens...

input:
"Hello" "-lo+p        +Please" //Spaces are irrelevant

output:
"PleaseHelp"

input:
"Mississippi" "-s-s-i-ppi+ng" //Operations can be in any order

output:
"Missing"

input:
"abcb" "-c -b +d"

output:
"abd"

input:
"1+1=2" "-1+22-=2+=23"

outut:
"22+1=23"
```

## Example Code

The example is Java, it's not golfed at all.

```
public static String refactor(String input, String swap) {
    int pointer = 0;
    String[] commands = swap.replace(" ", "").split("(?=[-+])");

    for (String s : commands) {
        if (s.startsWith("+")) {
            input = input.substring(0, pointer) + s.substring(1) + input.substring(pointer, input.length());
            pointer = 0;
        } else {
            if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                String remove = s.substring(1);
                for (int i = pointer; i < input.length(); i++) {
                    if (input.substring(i, i + remove.length() > input.length() ? input.length() : i + remove.length()).equals(remove)) {
                        pointer = i;
                        input = input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + remove.length(), input.length());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

## Rules

- Standard Loopholes Apply
- Shortest code, in bytes, wins

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96473/47066)

Comment: What should be the output for `aaa -a`?

Comment: `|aa` with the pipe being the pointer.

Comment: @Emigna Upon looking at the question in question, I believe the implementation of mine would be much different.

Comment: What happens with `-` if the suffix isn't found?

Comment: `aaa -b +b` would result with `aaab` because the pointer would go all the way to the end.

Comment: Can we assume input without spaces...

Comment: Your example is abit confusing, You should seperate what is the input and what is the refractor string to make it more clear

Comment: @Zgarb Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3 (<s>164</s> <s>194</s> <s>186</s> <s>181</s> <s>168</s> 165 bytes)

```py
p=0
w,*x=input().split()
for i in x:
 if '-'>i:w,p=w[:p]+i[1:]+w[p:],0
 else:
  try:p=w.index(i[1:],p)
  except:p=len(w)
  w=w[:p]+w[p:].replace(i[1:],'',1)
print(w)
```

Example demonstrating the pointer moving to the end if it doesn't find a substring:

```
Input: HelloThere -x +Friend
Output: HelloThereFriend
```

Special thanks to Artyer for saving me 13 bytes.

Another thanks to Artyer for saving me another 3 bytes via the `beg` parameter of `index`.

Old answer:

```py
p=0
x=input().split()
w=x[0]
for i in x[1:]:
 if i[0]=='+':
  w=w[:p]+i[1:]+w[p:]
  p=0
 else:
  p=w[p:].index(i[1:])+p
  w=w[:p]+w[p:].replace(i[1:],'',1)
print(w)
```

Example demonstrating the pointer works (all the examples in the Q work even if you don't factor in the pointer and simply replace on first occurence):

```
Input: HelloThereCowboy -r -e -y +ySays +Oh
Output: OhHelloTheCowboySays
```

Edit: Since 2 minutes ago my answer is now invalid according to a comment by the asker.

> aaa -b +b would result with aaab because the pointer would go all the
>   way to the end.

Edit2: Fixed.

Comment: `w,*x=input().split()`, and `if'-'>i:` instead of `if i[0]=='+':`and tab character for 2 indents instead of 2 spaces will save some bytes

Comment: If I try to mix tabs and spaces I get `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. Thanks for the suggestions, I didn't know about those features! I'll begin adding them immediately.

Comment: @redstartcoder I guess the tab trick only works in Python 2. My bad

Comment: I could absolutely be wrong here, but I *think* strings have a `find` method which will return `-1` if it can't find the substring. Since -1 points to the back of the string, all you would need to do is take a modulus of `p` by the length of `w` which should mean you don't need a try-except.

Comment: I'll look into implementing it (I guess I'm not allowed to edit that comment?)

Comment: `-1%0` produces `ZeroDivisionError`, but `find` definitely works and I think is promising...

Comment: You would do `-1%len(str)` to get the index at the end of string. `str.index` and `str.find` also take a `start` parameter, so I assume you can replace `w[p:].index(i[1:])` with `w.index(i[1:],p)`. Overall, it would be ``else:p=(w.find(i[1:],p)+p)%len(p);w=w[:p]+w[p:].replace(i[1:],'',1)``.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as-is (even with `len(p)` to `len(w)`), I'll look into why when I wake up a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 97 Bytes

```
" "%(:s;0:p;{("-"0=={.s p>\?.-1={;;s,:p;}{:p;,:l;s p<s p l+>+:s;}if}{s p<\+s p>+:s;0:p;}if}/"\n"s
```

Test: [golfscript.tryitonline.net](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IiAiJSg6czswOnA7eygiLSIwPT17LnMgcD5cPy4tMT17OztzLDpwO317OnA7LDpsO3MgcDxzIHAgbCs-KzpzO31pZn17cyBwPFwrcyBwPis6czswOnA7fWlmfS8iXG4icw&input=U2ltcGxlIC1pbXBsICtuaXAgLWUgK2Vy)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can use the interpreter on [Try it online](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IiAiJSg6czswOnA7eygiLSIwPT17LnMgcD5cPy4tMT17OztzLDpwO317OnA7LDpsO3MgcDxzIHAgbCs-KzpzO31pZn17cyBwPFwrcyBwPis6czswOnA7fWlmfS8iXG4icw&input=U2ltcGxlIC1pbXBsICtuaXAgLWUgK2Vy), which does support input.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```
{s l←⍵0⋄s⊣{g←1↓⍵⋄'+'=⊃⍵:+s∘←(l↑s),g,l↓s⋄l∘←¯1+1⍳⍨g⍷s⋄+s∘←(l↑s),s↓⍨l+⍴g}¨{1↓¨⍵⊂⍨⍵=⊃⍵}' ',⍺}
```

This takes the string as its right argument, and the commands as its left argument, like so:

```
      '+Code -al +lf' {s l←⍵0⋄s⊣{g←1↓⍵⋄'+'=⊃⍵:+s∘←(l↑s),g,l↓s⋄l∘←¯1+1⍳⍨g⍷s⋄+s∘←(l↑s),s↓⍨l+⍴g}¨{1↓¨⍵⊂⍨⍵=⊃⍵}' ',⍺} 'Goal'
CodeGolf
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 117 bytes

```
(s,r,t='')=>r.match(/\S\w*/g).map(r=>(q=r.slice(1),r<'-'?(s=t+q+s.t=''):([b,...a]=s.split(q),t+=b,s=a.join(q))))&&t+s
```

Explanation: Instead of using a cumbersome pointer, I keep the left half of the string in `t` and the right half in `s`. Additionally, `split` and `join` are a convenient way to perform the removal.